# WPF : How to create separate Resources for each item in a bound ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, collections

I want to achieve the following:

- My ViewModel exposes a property named 'Categories' which is a collection of CategoryViewModel objects
- Each CategoryViewModel object exposes a property called 'Items' which is a collection of strings*.
- On my View, I want a TabControl with a TabItem for each object in the 'Categories' collection.
- The Content of each TabItem should be a xceed DataGrid control displaying the contents of the selected tab's Items collection.

  ```
  <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
      <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <xcdg:DataGridControl
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      AutoCreateColumns="True">
              </xcdg:DataGridControl>
          </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
  </TabControl>
  ```

This works ok when I bind directly to the ItemsSource property of the DataGridControl. However, in order to utilize all of the functionality of the DataGridControl, I need to bind the ItemsSource property of the DataGridControl to a DataGridCollectionViewSource object that is bound to my Items collection. I do this when the grid ISN'T nested in another control by creating a DataGridCollectionViewSource object in the Resources section of the UserControl and binding to that.

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="GridData"
            Source="{Binding Items}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <xcdg:DataGridControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GridData}}"
                AutoCreateColumns="True">
        </xcdg:DataGridControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How do I need to structure the XAML so that when the TabControl is being bound, a DataGridCollectionViewSource object is created for each TabItem so that the DataGridControl that is generated within the content of the TabItem can be bound to it?

Clear as mud, right? :)

Thanks!

### Notes:

*In the real solution the collection contains objects of a class that is more complex than a simple string, but a string was used to make the example more simple.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a bit of a long-shot, but could you use the DataGrid.Tag ...

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <xcdg:DataGridControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag}"
                AutoCreateColumns="True">
            <xcdg:DataGridControl.Tag>
                 <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="GridData"
                      Source="{Binding Items}" />
            </xcdg:DataGridControl.Tag>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Or ... resources can be defined on any FrameworkElement, so you could try:

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <xcdg:DataGridControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GridData}}"
                AutoCreateColumns="True">
            <xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
                 <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="GridData"
                      Source="{Binding Items}" />
            </xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

I don't use the eXceed Grid so cannot test whether these work - just a couple of ideas to try!

Colin E.

Comment: E: Thank you for the attempt. I tried both of your suggestions, and could not get either to work. You're second suggestion is close to what I tried via decyclone's suggestion of x:Shared. (if I could, i would give you rep for the suggetions)

Comment: No problem - all out of ideas now :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`x:Shared="True"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) attribute on a resource. That means a new instance is created for every use of that resource.

### Example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="GridData" 
        x:Shared="False"
        Source="{Binding Items}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a step in the right direction. I moved the declaration of the DataGridCollectionViewSource into the Resources property of the DataTemplate because this seemed to make more sense to me. (Because each DataGridControl does need it's own instance of the DataGridCollectionViewSource class, but each instance needs to be bound to a different collection.)

Comment: This compiles and runs without error, but does not achieve the desired effect. I get no data in my grids. 

Also, I'm curious why the x:Shared option did not appear in intellisense... weird.

Comment: @BigFunger: My mistake. It should actually be `x:Shared="False"`. We don't want to share it, right?